# Uninstall Python3.3.4 (previously installed via source code)

Tags: python, linux

How can I uninstall Python3.3.4 previously installed via source code?
During the installation I made:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3.4
make
sudo make install
```

I tried `sudo make uninstall` and `make unistall`, but nothing happened.

Comment: what do you mean 'nothing happened'? like literally nothing?

Comment: You should ask this question on http://http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for something unsubtle like

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/python3.3.4
```

assuming that's where Python was actually installed. But this looks unnatural, because why would anybody ever want to uninstall Python?

Also, if you have modified your PATH settings and the like you will have to undo those effect manually.

Comment: I made a mess, the first time I used "./configure" without "--prefix" how could I uninstall it? Because I think I installed python3.3.4 2 times

Comment: Just remove the Python you find at the default prefix (I seem to remember it's `/usr`, but you can do the research) in the same way. This doesn't mean you should remove `/usr`, just the directories and files added by the Python installation (I think /usr/lib/pythonXX and a few individual files in the Python 3.3 distribution, but I am dredging for this and can't guarantee correctness).

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the directory:

```
sudo rm -ri /opt/python3.3.4
```

Comment: Note that the `-i` option requires the user to confirm the deletion of each file. I personally prefer the silent option.